# XSLT search across multiple XML files

Tags: xslt

I'm using XSLTs and XML files to build a web page.  Let's say I've got data scattered across a few files, like so:

CoreOptions.xml:

```
<optionsets>
    <optionset id="yes-no">
        <option id="yes">Yes</option>
        <option id="no">No</option>
    </optionset>
    ...
</optionsets>
```

ProjectSpecificOptions.xml:

```
<optionsets>
    <optionset id="menu">
        <option id="1">Chicken</option>
        <option id="2">Fish</option>
    </optionset>
    ...
</optionsets>
```

Now, normally, I'd pull them in like this:

```
<xsl:param name="CoreOptionSets" select="document('CoreOptions.xml')/optionsets" />
<xsl:param name="ProjectOptionSets" select="document('ProjectSpecificOptions.xml')/optionsets" />
```

... and reference them by variable names.

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="$CoreOptionSets/optionset[id=....
```

However, I'm trying to set things up such that the transform neither knows nor cares which file the data actually lives in.  If I go for `optionset[@id='menu']`, I don't want to have to specify which file I'm pulling it out of.

How would I do something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can merge your sets adding this variable:

```
<xsl:variable name="AllSets" select="$CoreOptionSets | $ProjectOptionSets"/>
```

And then select your sets using:

```
$AllSets/optionset[@id='menu']
$AllSets/optionset[@id='yes-no']
```

Comment: I thought this answer was superfluous when I found the "collection()" function, but then "collection()" spontaneously stopped working for reasons I have yet to sort out.  This was a lifesaver.  Thank you!

Comment: You can use `collection()` but it requires a XSLT 2.0 processor.